# Invalid value error when using Chainlink Functions request script

Tags: chainlink

I am working through the *Adding Chainlink Functions to an Existing Project* tutorial: https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/resources/add-functions-to-projects

I am not trying to integrate my own project yet and am using the provided:

- FunctionsClient.sol
- Functions-request-source.js
- request.js

I did note that the tutorial at *Create a request script* point 6 it says to use

> `const source = ./Functions-request-source.js`

However, the request.js has this line:

> `const source = await fs.readFile("./Functions-request-source.js", "utf8");`

When using both options (after updating the first example to `const source = "./Functions-request-source.js"`) I get the same error.

When running request.js, I am receiving this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat> npx hardhat run scripts/request.js --network polygonMumbai     
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version

C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269
        const error: any = new Error(message);
                           ^
Error: invalid value for array (argument="value", value=420, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=contracts/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:168:42    at step (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:48:23)
.js:29:53)
    at C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:23:71    
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:19:12)
    at resolveAddresses (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\lib\index.js:119:12)
    at C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\contracts\src.ts\index.ts:150:20    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
PS C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat> npx hardhat run scripts/request.js --network polygonMumbai     
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version
```

I can bypass this error by placing 420 into an array `[420]` but I then receive this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat> npx hardhat run scripts/request.js --network polygonMumbai
secp256k1 unavailable, reverting to browser version

C:\Users\Coding\vscode\donateassist-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269
        const error: any = new Error(message);
                           ^
Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=["ETH","USD"], code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
    at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
    at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
    at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:285:21)
    at Function.BigNumber.from (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\bignumber\src.ts\bignumber.ts:289:23)
    at NumberCoder.encode (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\number.ts:25:27)
    at C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:71:19
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at pack (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:54:12)     
    at TupleCoder.encode (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\tuple.ts:54:20)
    at AbiCoder.encode (C:\Users\Coding\vscode\x-functions-hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\abi-coder.ts:111:15)
```

Any help most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

its a bit hard to diagnose with the information you've provided...

Its worth noting though that the documentation gets data from different repos

1. For [this section](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/resources/add-functions-to-projects#get-the-dependency-contracts-and-scripts) you get the dependencies, tooling and some of the starter kit stuff --- and that comes from [this starter kit repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/functions-hardhat-starter-kit)
2. But for this [this section](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions/resources/add-functions-to-projects#deploy-a-consumer-contract) and also for the request.js script ,you're actually using [the examples repo](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/smart-contract-examples)  and **not** the starter kit repo.

You can see this from the url that `curl` is fetching data from.

This may be the source of your confusion.  Could you please try running through your code with this in mind and see if that helps skip the errors?

Comment: Thank you, I made a mistake setting it up correctly. I'm no longer getting the same errors.